# How can I select the bottom-most populated field in a column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have several sparsely-populated columns:

```
    1    8       9    
    3    1   7    
    7            2    
         3
```

I'd like the following values from the bottoms of the columns: `7`, `3`, `7`, `2`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This formula returns the number of the last non-zero cell in the column A:

```
=arrayformula(max(if(A1:A<>"";row(A1:A);1)))
```

Then you can use =index to get the value of the corresponding sell.